# testing excel vba code and examining object in watch window when Excel crashed and required "restart" and now macros "disabled" and wont execute

Tags: excel, vba

Testing excel vba code and examining objects in the watch window when Excel crashed and required "restart" and now macros "disabled" and won't execute. I have checked all the "Trust Settings and they are fine, but code still won't execute.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

[[image: Excel SpreadSheet][1]]

[image]

Comment: This should resolve it: https://www.howtogeek.com/812574/enable-macros-in-excel/

Comment: thank you for your help, but I have tried all this, and it does not work.  I am the author of macros on this PC and nothing is being brought in over the internet.  Everything was fine and I was inspecting objects in the watch browser.  Excel crashed and required a restart.  When Excel restarted it disabled macros saying they from an "untrusted" source

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Can you add screenshots of any warnings you're getting when  you open your document to your question above?

Comment: Screen Shots Added

Comment: What I can do is open a new project and then import classes and modules then save it as a "macro-enabled workbook" I can work on the project with no problem. However, once I save it, problem starts again.

Comment: I searched google for 'Microsoft has blocked Macros from running because the source is untrusted' and found this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-has-blocked-macros-from-running-because/4bf4eb8d-5545-4e00-a6a7-a0801e264cc2 Have you tried the 72 solutions on this page?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I think I have the problem fixed.  I had to uninstall Excel reinstall it and import the classes into a new project.